# How do I properly use and access pointers to arrays inside or outside of different functions?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

I am reading data out of a file.csv that has two columns into arrays, for which i have a function, and I then try to use these arrays inside of other functions.

But when I check the values held by the array inside of the reading function it shows other values than when I check them inside of another function.

As I am fairly new to using pointers in combination with different data types I am proboably just making a mistake accessing them inside or outside of functions so any hints are welcome.

My **read_csv** function to read this file is in **files.cpp** and looks like this:

```
int read_csv(std::string Input_file, double* alt, double* vel) {

    //opens file here

    int i = 0; int j = 0;
    while (Infile.good()) {
        std::string line;
        // Read whole line
        while (getline(Infile, line))
        {
            std::istringstream iline(line);
            // Seperate line by the delimiter
            while (getline(iline, line, ';'))
            {
                if (j == 1)
                {
                    // Column 2: velocity
                    vel[i] = strtod(line.c_str(), NULL);
                    std::cout << "vel: " << vel[i] << std::endl;
                    i++; j--;
                }
                else if (j == 0)
                {
                    // Column 1: altitude
                    alt[i] = (strtod(line.c_str(), NULL));
                    std::cout << "alt: " << alt[i] << std::endl;
                    i++; j++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

After this function is executed the Output is as I expect it to be:

```
alt: 1
vel: 1
alt: 2
vel: 2
alt: 3
vel: 3
alt: 4
vel: 4
```

But when I try to use these arrays inside of the **main.cpp**:

```
int main() {
    double* vel = new double[4];
    double* alt = new double[4];

    read_csv(Input_file, alt, vel);

    double** Output_data = new double* [2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        Output_data[i] = new double[4];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        Output_data[i][0] = alt[i];
        Output_data[i][1] = vel[i];
        std::cout << alt[i] << std::endl;
        std::cout << vel[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The Output looks like this:

```
1
-6.27744e+66
-6.27744e+66
1
2
-6.27744e+66
-6.27744e+66
2
```

which seems to me like in between the values where the delimiter inside the file was is now two values that haven't appeard inside the reading function.

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, the preferred method is to use `std::vector` and pass it by reference to each function that needs the container.  Pass by constant reference if the function doesn't modify the vector.

Comment: Or create a `struct altvel { double alt, vel; }` and let the function return a `std::vector<altvel>`. Don't use `new[]`/`delete[]` for this.

Comment: `Output_data` points to an array of 2 `double*`, but you try accessing `Output_data[2]` and `Output_data[3]`, which leads to undefined behavior. I think that's a good enough reason to start using vectors instead, and never touch `new` again.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful alternatives. I will try to implement them to avoid this problem.

Comment: @ViktorHoffmann Here's an idea: https://godbolt.org/z/KaMGqhn6b

Comment: *"The **file.csv** I am reading looks like this"* -- this should not be necessary for your question. When you asked your question (as text), you were able to phrase it in terms of values seen in one function and values seen in another. Don't add complications in your [mre]. Instead of reading from a file (which works), simply hardcode values within `read_csv()`. So something more like `void init_values(double* alt, double* vel) { for ( int i = 0; i < 4; ++i ) { vel[i] = i; alt[i] = i; std::cout << "vel: " << vel[i] << '\n'; std::cout << "alt: " << alt[i] << '\n'; } }`.